# Time complexity for an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

> > How do you realize that
> >     $$(3log^2(n) + 55log(n^{10})+8log(n))*log(n) \neq \Omega(log^{10}(n))$$
> >     ,where $log^x(n)$ means $(log(n))^x$

I know that by definition, if $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ then there exists a constant $c_1$ such that $$0 \leq c_1 *g(n) \leq f(n)$$ for all $ n > n_0$. In our case it yields
$$c_1*log^{10}(n) \leq (3log^2(n) + 55log(n^{10})+8log(n))*log(n) $$

$\Rightarrow$

$$c_1 \leq \frac{3log^3(n)}{log^{10}(n)} + \frac{55log(n^{10})*log(n)}{log^{10}(n)} + \frac{8log^{2}(n)}{log^{10}(n)}$$

RHS: It's fairly easy to see that the denominator is larger than the nominator of both the first and third term, which means that $55log(n^{10})*log(n) > log^{10}(n) + c_1$ for some $n_0$ if the first equation holds.

I am just not able to see how to manipulate the equation to realize it...

Comment: you should mention that there exists $c_1 > 0$ and $n_0 > 1$ such your inequality holds for all $n > n_0$.

Comment: Good point, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take it from where you paused. Assume your claim is true, that is the following is correct
$$(3\log^2(n) + 55\log(n^{10})+8\log(n))\log(n) \neq \Omega(\log^{10}(n))$$
Then there exists $c_1 > 0 $ and $n_0 > 1$ such that for all $n > n_0$,we have
$$c_1\log^{10}(n) \leq (3\log^2(n) + 55\log(n^{10})+8\log(n))\log(n) $$
Divide both sides by $\log(n)$
$$c_1\log^{9}(n) \leq (3\log^2(n) + 55\log(n^{10})+8\log(n)) $$
Use $\log a^b = b \log a$
$$c_1\log^{9}(n) \leq (3\log^2(n) + 550\log(n)+8\log(n)) $$
Divide again by $\log (n)$
$$c_1\log^{8}(n) \leq (3\log(n) + 558) \tag{1}$$
Your task now is to find me a $c_1 > 0$ and $n_0 > 1$, such that for all $n > n_0$ such that $(1)$ is true. Written differently,
$$\exists n_0 > 1 \quad \mid  \quad 0<c_1\leq (\frac{3}{\log^{7}(n) } + \frac{558}{\log^8(n)}), \ \forall n \geq n_0$$
The above is clearly not true. The larger $n$ is, the upper bound goes to zero. By the sandwich theorem, you get that $c_1$ has to be zero. By contradiction, the initial hypothesis is false.

Comment: The $loga^b = b*log a$ trick did it! Clear explanation - Thanks!

Comment: btw try using $\log$ not $log$ .. just add a backslash ;) and no need for an asterisk for multiplication .. good luck

Comment: Thanks - Got it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote $y = \log n$, then our inequality transforms to
$$c_1 \leq \frac{3}{y^7} + \frac{550}{y^8} + \frac{8}{y^8}$$

and we need to prove that for any $c_1 > 0$ this inequality is violated for arbitrary large $y$.

Let us take any $y > \max(1, \frac{550 + 8 + 3}{c_1})$. Then we have $\frac{3}{y^7} + \frac{550}{y^8} + \frac{8}{y^8} < \frac{550 + 8 + 3}{y} < \frac{550 + 8 + 3}{\frac{550 + 8 + 3}{c_1}} = c_1$